# What is the IBM Cognos Report icon with an arrow in the bottom-left corner?

Tags: cognos-bi, cognos-10

I have two reports in "My Folders" that have icons with a tiny arrow in the bottom-left corner. These icons are very similar to the other report icons except for the tiny arrow. (see image)

What is the difference between these two icons? Is there a reference somewhere that lists what all the IBM Cognos icons mean?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can derive the meaning of the little arrow by looking at the name of the second report. It says "shortcut to" which means that this entry is a logical link to the report which is probably residing in some other directory. Shortcuts in Cognos work very much like links in the Unix filesystem allowing you to make the same object available in several locations.

Upon creation Cognos automatically adds the prefix "Shortcut to" to the original name of the object pointed to. However, the name can be changed afterwards as was the case in your first example report.